# How to use authorization for node.js services?

Tags: node.js

I have written some Node.js services that available by http protocol.

One of them is upload file service.

User can make request to specific endpoin and upload file.

How to prevent using the service for not authorized users?

So, now anyone can send file to service.

1. What is practic to do that for some services node.js?
2. Which any other security features to take into account?

Comment: Do you use any framework, e.g. Express? One way of doing so is [JWT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON_Web_Token) like [express-jwt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-jwt) for Express.

Comment: Yes, I use it, but some services uses only http lib

Comment: I wonder about professional way to do that

Comment: The general approach is to use middleware that checks for the presence of some credential on every incoming request (that needs auth).  The credential can be either something that is manually provided with every API call (such as a specific http header) or it can be something that is established once and then put in a cookie that comes more automatically with every request (depending upon the client).

Comment: You can also you npm packages that are not framework specific to use JWT. I can recommend `jsonwebtoken` - https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonwebtoken.

Comment: Hi,  it is interesting for me too, I think middleware is good suggestion, but it requires express.js also middleware works in express directly inside endpoint request, so better to have a separate middleware before node.ja service. It is questiin for me too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you want some endpoints to be private so that you can prevent using the service for not authorized users.
also, you are using  Express but some services use only HTTP library.

**if you want to use JWT:**
jsonwebtoken (https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonwebtoken)

**if you want to use Session:**
creates some sort of guaranteed unique cookie value and sets that as a cookie on the response save it in a variable on memory.
letter when there will be a request, check the response cookie and validate it. This is an over-complicated process.

**if you want to use secret key:**
if you are unable to use any of these. use a secret key process.
means your user will provide a key(like a password) and file. you will have some pre-defined keys in an array, check first if the user input key is valid, then only process the upload file.

I understand that the answer is not just "**use X**", because I do not have a particular idea of what you can use in your system as you are using (express and also sometimes core HTTP library ). if you faced any issue or do not understand any point, let me know. I will try my best to help.

Comment: Hi, where jwt should be placed? As separate d servuce like a http router to concrete service? Not goid idea to duplicate jwt logic in each service node.js it must be in anothrr separated layer

Comment: If to use jwt it means to send token in each http requst to service?

Comment: The login process will create JWT and send it with the response header as cookies.  After that with each request from the user , the cookie will be sent automatically to the server . You have to parse the cookie and then chek the cookie JWT . This checking of cookie JWT. Have to be done every time some one hit the protected routes (private links). But her will be created single time and will be valid for 15 ,30 ,60 minutes or more according to your use case

Comment: You have to create middleware for the protected routes and the middleware will check cookie and take the JWT , then authenticate the JWT .

Comment: Could you explain more about middleware is it another node.js service, file?

Comment: @Jessy Since this is not your question and comments are not suited to go into detail, feel free to ask a new question.

Comment: Yes, @jessy please ask new question , as it is not possible to give answer in reply box (due to short space , no newline and other issues)

Comment: Middleware  is function , which stay between 2 function. Like function1-> middleware->function2.